# How to instantiate inner class of abstract class - java

Tags: java, instantiation, inner-classes

Consider

```
public abstract class Foo{

    ///some code

    class Foo1 extends Foo
    {
        //// some code
    }

    class Foo2 extends Foo
    {
        ///// some code 
    }
}
```

How can I create an object of the inner classes?

Comment: Are you sure you need `Foo1` to both *be* a `Foo` *and* have a reference to another `Foo`? Perhaps you meant for `Foo1` to be a `static` nested class, so you can just use `new Foo.Foo1()`?

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html : "An instance of InnerClass **can exist only within an instance of OuterClass**"

Comment: We need any instance of outer class to create inner class object. Like `Foo f = new Foo(){};
  Foo.Foo1 f1 = f.new Foo1();`

Answer (score 1):

To instantiate nested non-static (inner) class, you need an instance of enclosing class.

But your enclosing class is abstract, so you can't instantiate it. What should you do?

If you really need **non-static** nested class, then the only option is to *extend* the abstract class and instantiate the inner class using instance of extending class.

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public class Foo1 extends Foo {
    }

    public static class FooImpl extends Foo {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new FooImpl();
        Foo1 foo1 = foo.new Foo1();
    }
}
```

Comment: 'Inner non-static' is a tautology, as is 'non-static inner'. Unclear what you're talking about.

Comment: I mean `Nested` of course. Inner == nested non-static. As non-native english speaker I always confuse notion of these words (`nested` and `inner`). Edit the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need another *top level* class extending Foo:

```
class Foo3 extends Foo {
  Foo foo;

  Foo3(){
   foo= new this.Foo2();
  }
}
```

or declare a `static` inner class:

```
public abstract class Foo{

    ///some code

    class Foo1 extends Foo
    {
        //// some code
    }

    class Foo2 extends Foo
    {
        ///// some code 
    }

    static class Foo3 extends Foo {
      Foo foo;

      Foo3(){
       foo= new this.Foo2();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be *top level*. A `static` nested class will also work.

Comment: Not necessarily, you just need any instance of `Foo` to use as an enclosing instance. Something like `new Foo().new Foo.Foo2()` would work too.

Comment: @JornVernee `new Foo()` doesn't work since `Foo` is `abstract`.

Comment: @Andreas Good point, a subtype of `Foo` then. I guess I read this answer incorrectly any ways.

Comment: What language is this? :) Not java anyway.

Comment: @Andreas *"It doesn't have to be top level. A static nested class will also work."* That's true, but my impression was that the OP didn't wanted *static* inner classes... I added this to the answer.

Comment: Your code is still incorrect. What this (`Foo foo = foo;` ) mean? The instantiation syntax is also wrong. `new this.Foo2();` should be `this.new Foo2();`

Comment: @djxak *"What this (Foo foo = foo; ) mean?"* this is a `package private` member variable of class `Foo3`, isn't it?

Comment: `Foo foo = foo` won't compile, because you cannot initialize a field to the value of itself, given that the field doesn't exist before the initializer completes. Eclipse compiler says: *"Cannot reference a field before it is defined"*

Comment: @Andreas *"Foo foo = foo won't compile"* that's correct, I changed the answer, Thank you.